# Wiederherstellen des ursprünglichen Zustands einer Frage

Tags: support

Ich bitte **mit sehr großem Nachdruck** darum, die Frage [Was ist mit »Österreichisch« gemeint (in sprachlicher Hinsicht)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22400/1487) wieder in jenen Zustand zurückzuversetzen, in dem sie war, bevor Takkat sie mit einer seiner eigenen Fragen vereint hat. Konkret soll bitte wieder [diese Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22401/1487) zu ihrer ursprünglichen Frage zurück verschoben werden und es soll wieder möglich sein, die Frage zu editieren, die Antwort zu editieren, Kommentare zu verfassen und neue Antworten auf diese Frage zu geben.

---

#### Begründung

Auf Stackexchange kann man Fragen posten, man kann Antworten posten, und es gibt ausdrücklich auch die Möglichkeit, beides zugleich zu tun: [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.13236727.1797306522.1664110583-1196244438.1660799835). Das wird zwar selten genutzt, wird von den Machern von Stackexchange aber ausdrücklich angeboten, für den Fall, das jemand sein Wissen teilen möchte.

Am 18. März 2015 (also vor 7 Jahren) habe ich genau das gemacht. Mir fiel nämlich auf, dass vor allem Besucher von German.stackexchange, die aus Deutschland kommen, gerne mal den Begriff *»Österreichisch«* verwenden und damit die in Österreich gesprochene Sprache meinen. Dagegen spricht zunächst auch gar nichts. Dabei wird aber sehr häufig *Österreichisch* als Gegensatz zu *Hochdeutsch* verwendet, womit mit *Hochdeutsch* die in Deutschland gesprochene Sprache gemeint ist. Österreichisch wird also so hingestellt, als wäre es etwas anderes als Hochdeutsch. Belege dafür stehen am Ende dieses Postings.

Daher war es mir wichtig, festzustellen, was der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* denn überhaupt bedeutet. Ich habe dazu eine Frage, und in derselben Millisekunde die dazugehörende Antwort gepostet:

- Frage: [Was ist mit »Österreichisch« gemeint (in sprachlicher Hinsicht)?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22400/1487)
- [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22401/1487)

Wie man sieht, wenn man den Links folgt, steht meine Antwort seit vielen Jahren nicht mehr bei der Frage, die ich explizit geschrieben habe, um diese Antwort geben zu können.

Der Moderator Takkat hat nämlich meine Frage mit einer seiner eigenen Fragen (die er noch dazu selbst für schlecht hält, siehe [Kommentar von ihm selbst](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/unterschied-zwischen-einer-sprachvariet%C3%A4t-und-einem-dialekt-am-beispiel-%C3%96sterrei/22401#comment56278_11096)) vereint. Seine Frage lautete: [Unterschied zwischen einer Sprachvarietät und einem Dialekt am Beispiel Österreichisch?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11096/1487) »Vereinen« heißt: Er hat meine Frage stehen lassen, hat sie gesperrt, so dass niemand mehr weitere Antworten oder Kommentare posten kann, und hat alle Antworten, die meine Frage beantwortet haben, zu seiner eigenen Frage verschoben, wo sie nun zum Teil wie Themenverfehlungen wirken, weil sie ja nicht geschrieben wurden um Takkats Frage zu beantworten (Unterschied Varietät-Dialekt), sondern meine Frage (Was bedeutet *»Österreichisch«*?).

Seine Frage und meine sind einander zwar ähnlich, aber eben nicht gleich. Mir ging es **NICHT** darum, den Unterschied zwischen den Begriffen *Varietät* und *Dialekt* zu klären, auch wenn sich die in Österreich gesprochene Sprache dafür als gutes Beispiel eignet. Mit ging es ganz klar und ausdrücklich darum, den Begriff **Österreichisch** klarer abzugrenzen. Als ich damals diese Frage+Antwort-Einheit geschrieben habe, habe ich das auch getan, um zukünftig, wann immer ich bemerkte, dass der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* falsch oder missverständlich wird, mit einem einfachen Link auf diese Frage verweisen zu können.

Seit Takkat die Einheit aus Frage und Antwort zerstört und meine Antwort seiner eigenen Frage einverleibt hat, habe ich aber nicht mehr die Möglichkeit, das mit einer kurzen Bemerkung und einem Link zu tun, sondern ich müsste jedesmal einen Link zur Frage posten, einen zweiten Link zur Antwort, und müsste erklären, warum die Antwort bei einer Frage steht, zu der sie gar nicht gehört. Bevor ich das alles schreibe, lasse ich es meist ganz bleiben, was aber so ziemlich genau das Gegenteil dessen ist, weswegen ich 2015 diese Frage+Antwort-Einheit verfasst habe.

Bevor Takkat die Antwort von der Frage getrennt hat, habe ich noch öfter auf diese Frage+Antwort-Einheit verweisen, wenn man aber jetzt diesen Links folgt, erreicht man nur eine Frage ohne Antworten. Auch andere haben früher diese Frage verlinkt:

- Frage [Ist „ka“ ein österreichisches „kein“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22316/ist-ka-ein-%C3%B6sterreichisches-kein) von c.p.
- Meine Antwort auf die Frage [Dialects of Austria—Resources?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/23847/1487)
- Meine Antwort auf die Frage [Can other verbs form contractions like "gemma"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22474/1487)
- Meine Antwort auf die Frage [Auf Östereichisch: was ist die korrekte Form für Zeitangaben in der Vergangenheit?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34107/1487)
- Meine Antwort auf die Frage [Etwas leinwand finden](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71762/1487)

---

#### Es gibt einen zweiten Grund, um Takkats Aktion rückgängig zu machen:

Meine und Takkats Frage erfüllen nicht die Bedingungen, die erforderlich sind, um zwei Fragen zu mergen.

Ich zitiere wörtlich und mit identischer Formatierung aus der Meta-Diskussion [What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/183215)

> ### When should questions be *merged*?
>
> Questions should be merged if one question is an *exact* duplicate of another (i.e., when its answers would make **perfect** sense on the other question), ...

Meine Frage (Was bedeutet *»Österreichisch«*?) ist **KEIN** exaktes Duplikat von Takkats Frage (Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einer Varietät und einem Dialekt?) und sie macht unter Takkats Frage auch keineswegs *perfekt* Sinn, weil ich in meiner Antwort auf den Begriff *»Varietät«* überhaupt nicht eingehe. Der Begriff wird in meiner Antwort nur einmal, und das auch eher beiläufig erwähnt, jedenfalls nicht so, dass man aus meiner Antwort herauslesen könnte, was eine Varietät denn eigentlich ist.

Daher hätten diese beiden Fragen niemals vereint werden dürfen.

Daher bitte nochmals **mit sehr großem Nachdruck** darum, den ursprünglichen Zustand (vor der Vereinigung mit Takkats Frage) wiederherzustellen.

---

Noch eine Anmerkung:

Ich habe die Frage und die Antwort vor 7 Jahren geschrieben und habe inzwischen auch viel dazugelernt. Ich würde daher gerne sowohl die Frage als auch die Antwort an einigen Stellen etwas zurechtrücken. Das macht aber nur Sinn, wenn die Antwort wieder unter der extra für sie geschaffenen Frage steht.

---

#### Belege für die Existenz von Aussagen der Art »Österreichisch ist nicht Hochdeutsch«

In dem Artikel [Österreich kämpft gegen deutschländisches Deutsch](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/oesterreich-geht-gegen-hochdeutsch-vor-a-973490.html) aus dem Magazin *der Spiegel* stehen diese Sätze:

> - Österreich geht gegen Hochdeutsch vor
> - ... weil insbesondere Kinder und Jugendliche sich vermehrt vom hochdeutschen Sprachgebrauch in den Medien beeinflussen lassen ...
> - Um den Wortschatz Austrias auch künftig lebendig zu halten, soll ab sofort in den Klassenzimmern Memory gespielt werden: mit Karten, die verschiedene Begriffe auf Hochdeutsch, Schweizer Deutsch und österreichischem Deutsch benennen und voneinander abgrenzen.
> - ..., dass laut einer Umfrage etwa die Hälfte der Befragten das Hochdeutsche für korrekter als das Österreichische hält.

Diese seltsame Sichtweise auf das, was in Österreich gesprochen wird, ist auch in vielen anderen Medien und Webseiten anzutreffen:

- [Hochdeutsch und Österreichisch - Zuordnungsübung](http://faculty.mercer.edu/weintraut_ej/style/Austrian1.htm)
- [Deutsch und Österreichisch unterscheiden sich mehr voneinander, als man zunächst glaubt.](https://www.zeit.de/zett/2018-11/diese-woerter-musst-du-kennen-wenn-du-in-oesterreich-ernst-genommen-werden-willst?utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F)
- [Die österreichische Sprache wird nach und nach vom Hochdeutschen verdrängt.](https://www.n-tv.de/wissen/Osterreichisch-wandelt-sich-Hochdeutsch-setzt-sich-mehr-und-mehr-durch-article6939841.html)
- [Grosso modo vertraten die Diskussionspartner die Auffassung, lediglich das bundesdeutsche Deutsch sei "echtes Hochdeutsch", Österreichisch lediglich ein hässlicher Dialekt desselben.](https://www.wienerzeitung.at/meinung/gastkommentare/2123248-Das-Verblassen-des-Oesterreichischen.html)
- [Das Österreichische wird vermehrt vom hochdeutschen Sprachgebrauch in den Medien beeinflusst.](https://www.mein-oesterreich.info/wissenswertes/oesterreichisches-deutsch.htm)

Diese Liste ließe sich beliebig lange fortführen. Weil es so viele Belege dafür gibt, gehe ich davon aus, dass das nicht Einzelmeinungen von einigen wenigen Personen sind, sondern dass das die vorherrschende Meinung in Deutschland ist. Eine Klarstellung, was der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* bedeutet, scheint mir daher gerade auf einer Website, die sich mit der deutschen Sprache beschäftigt, durchaus angebracht zu sein.

Answer (score 2):

Einen Merge rückgängig zu machen, ist nur für SE-Mitarbeiter möglich und auch dann ziemlich aufwendig. **Falls wir so etwas anfragen sollten, brauchen wir ziemlich triftige Gründe, dass so – und nur so – Fragen, Inhalte, Stimmen, usw. gerettet werden, die den Aufwand wert sind.** Ich werde mich deswegen nicht damit aufhalten, ob die Entscheidungen, die zum Status Quo¹ geführt haben, gut waren, sondern nur, ob eine (praktisch mögliche) Änderung des Status Quo¹ den Aufwand lohnt, sei es, dass wir den Merge ungeschehen machen oder dass wir die Fragen wiedereröffnen.

Ich denke, dass dies nicht der Fall ist, beide Fragen – ob einzeln oder zusammen – eine Reihe von Problemen aufweisen.

- Die existierenden Antworten beantworten zum Teil völlig unterschiedliche tatsächliche Fragen, manchmal mehrere auf einmal (wodurch sie ziemlich lang werden). Dies belegt, dass die Frage zu weit gestellt ist. Zwar kann man einer Frage nur bedingt ihre Antworten vorwerfen, aber ein Neuanfang ist allemal besser, als jetzt Frage und Antworten aufeinander zuzuschneiden.
- Die Frage »Was ist mit ›Österreichisch‹ gemeint (in sprachlicher Hinsicht)?« mag auf den ersten Blick ziemlich klar und eindeutig erscheinen, ist es aber nun mal leider nicht. Verschiedene Menschen meinen mit *Österreichisch* in verschiedenen Kontexten verschiedene Dinge und bestenfalls können wir mögliche Bedeutungen auflisten und die Problematik differenzieren. Ohne weitere Spezifikationen ist die Frage in etwa so gut für das Stack-Exchange-Format geeignet wie »Was ist Religion?«, »Was ist eine Programmiersprache?«, oder eben »Was ist die deutsche Sprache?«.

  Nun kann man sicher eine Frage nach Verwendungen des Begriffs *Österreichisch* stellen (entweder als Überblick oder in einem gegebenen Kontext), aber das muss dann so geschehen, dass ein klarer Fokus der Antworten begünstigt wird.
  Dies gelang der vorliegende Frage nun mal eben nicht (siehe die entsprechenden anderen Punkte).
- Die andere Frage (»Unterschied zwischen einer Sprachvarietät und einem Dialekt am Beispiel Österreichisch?«) mag sich auf den ersten Blick von der anderen unterscheiden, beruht aber im Wesentlichen auch darauf, dass man hier klärt, was man unter *Österreichisch* versteht. Außerdem geht es hier primär um linguistische Facheinordnungen, welche eben nicht Thema dieser Seite sind.
- Deine Antworten auf beide Fragen (welche Du ja retten und verbessern möchtest) enthalten ausgiebige Abschweifungen zu Themen wie dem Unterschied zwischen Bundesdeutsch und Österreichischem Deutsch. Ich sehe zunächst nicht, wieso diese für die Beantwortung der eigentlichen Frage nötig sind – was schon einmal nahelegt, dass sie nicht so klar ist, wie vielleicht erhofft. Aber selbst wenn wir als gegeben ansehen, dass sie es sind, müssen ja alle Antworten solche Ausschweifungen aufweisen, was wiederum nahelegt, dass die Frage zu weit gestellt ist.

Nota bene: Ich sage nicht, dass die erste Frage (»Was ist mit ›Österreichisch‹ gemeint …?«) off-topic ist oder unwichtig ist, sondern nur dass sie zu weit und anderweitig ungeeignet für diese Seite ist.

#### Wie soll es weitergehen?

Ich bleibe bei [dem](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/unterschied-zwischen-einer-sprachvariet%c3%a4t-und-einem-dialekt-am-beispiel-%c3%96sterrei#comment56279_11096), was ich bei Sperrung der Frage schrieb:
Zukünftige Fragen zu dem Thema müssen meiner Meinung nach enger umrissen sein, sodass klar ist, was die Frage beantwortet und was nicht, und zu ihrer Beantwortung nicht äußerst lange, ausschweifende Aufsätze oder lange Listen von Unterschieden nötig sind.
Diese Fragen und Antworten dürfen sich natürlich gerne des bestehenden Materials bedienen, aufeinander verweisen, und es darf auch Inhaltsverzeichnisse auf Meta, im Tag-Wiki o. Ä. geben.

Ein paar Beispiele für Fragen, die man vermutlich sinnvoll stellen könnte:

- > Gibt es offizielle Instanzen für österreichisches Deutsch? Wer muss sich daran halten und wer tut es de facto?
- > Wie kann man die österreichischen Varianten des Deutschen mit anderen in Relation setzen? (Relationen wie »ist Dialekt von« oder »ist Dachsprache von«.)
- > Gibt es eine sprachwissenschaftliche Definition von »Österreichisch«?
- > Was sind die wesentlichen grammatikalischen Unterschiede zwischen österreichischem, schweizerischem, und Bundesdeutsch?

¹ Fragen zusammengeführt und mit historischem Lock versehen.

Comment: Danke, das ist eine akzeptable Antwort. Mein Lösungsvorschlag: Ich post eine ganz neue Frage, wieder samt Antwort, (eventuell auch mehrere, du hast da sehr gute Vorschläge geliefert, die ich gerne aufgreife) und ihr löscht danach meine alte Frage. Eventuell sollte man dann auch Takkats Frage löschen, weil sie auch zu weit gefasst ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Der Vorschlag steht seit sieben Jahren, aber bitte in mehreren Fragen mit kompakten Antworten – sonst wiederholt sich das Problem nur. Ob wir die alten Fragen löschen, wird sich dann zeigen, aber ich sehe auch keinen großen Schaden sie mit Historical Lock stehen zu lassen.

Comment: Neue Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/71783/1487

Comment: Bitte löscht nun diese Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/22400/1487und bitte auch diese Antwort: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22401/1487. Leider bin ich offenbar nicht dazu berechtigt, das selbst zu tun. Die Frage habe ich bereits entsprechend geflaggt, bei der Antwort kann ich leider nicht mal das tun.

Answer (score -1):

Zunächst: Es ist kein Problem, eine Frage zu posten und selbst zu beantworten. Das ist im Gegenteil sogar erwünscht!

Danke auch für deinen Versuch, Klarheit in das Forum zu bringen, was die Verwendung der Begriffe angeht. Ich stimme mit dir in diesem Anliegen überein und möchte dich darin unterstützen.

Gegenwärtig besteht mein Hauptgrund, die Österreichisch-Frage nicht wieder zu eröffnen, darin, dass sie in meinen Augen auf Meta gestellt werden sollte. So, wie sie gegenwärtig gestellt ist, geht es nicht um die Frage, was Österreichisch ist, sondern wie der Begriff hier im Forum verwendet wird.

So wie ich die Frage verstehe, addressiert sie das Problem, dass der Begriff hier mitunter falsch oder missverständlich verwendet wird. Das ist in meinen Augen eine Frage über das Forum, und gehört auf Meta. Wenn wir die passende Meta-Frage haben, eignet sich das sehr gut dazu, dahin zu verlinken, wannimmer jemand den Begriff missverständlich verwendet.

Spricht etwas dagegen, eine Frage auf Meta zu stellen, die die Begriffsverwendung von *Österreichisch* problematisiert?

Comment: Ja, dagegen spricht der Umstand, dass die Frage nicht auf den Gebrauch hier im Forum abzielt, sondern auf den Gebrauch in Deutschland (aber durchaus auch in Österreich, der Schweiz und anderen Ländern). Kein einziges der Beispiele, in denen ich am Ende meines Postings belegt habe, dass der Begriff missverstanden wird, stammt aus German.stackexchange. Das sind ausschließlich Beispiele von anderen Webseiten. Es geht nicht darum, wie der Begriff hier auf German.stackexchange verwendet wird, sondern darum, wie der Begriff überhaupt verwendet wird.

Comment: Zweiter Grund: Für die Fragen, die auf German.Meta.stackexchange gewälzt werden, interessiert sich der durchschnittliche Besucher von German.stackexchange nicht die Bohne. Frage und Antwort würden hier vom Zielpublikum nicht wahrgenommen werden.

Comment: Gegenfrage: Spricht irgend etwas dagegen, meine Bitte zu erfüllen? Was spricht dagegen, auf German.stackexchange danach zu fragen, was der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* bedeutet?

Comment: Dann verstehe ich die Frage noch nicht richtig. Sie beginnt mit: "Gelegentlich liest man hier im Deutsch-Forum Fragen und Antworten, in denen es darum geht, ob ein bestimmtes Wort ein österreichisches Wort sein könnte. Das halte ich für problematisch, wenn nicht eindeutig definiert ist, was mit »Österreichisch« (in Bezug auf Sprache) gemeint ist."  Das ist für mich eine Meta-Frage

Comment: Dass die Verwendung des Begriffs auf German.stackexchange der Anlass war, Frage und Antwort zu schreiben, bedeutet ja keines keinesweg, dass das Problem ausschließlich auf German.stackexchange und sonst nirgendwo bestünde. Viele Fragen hier auf German.stackexchange werden damit eingeleitet, dass der Autor bei der Lektüre einer anderen Frage auf etwas aufmerksam wurde, dem man nun genauer nachgehen will. Ich habe sicher gut ein Dutzend Mal meiner eigenen Fragen so eingeleitet, und andere Autoren haben das ebenfalls mehrmals ...

Comment: ... so gemacht (Beispiele von mir: [a](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/26119/1487), [b](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/32562/1487), [c](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/17683/1487), [d](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/33998/1487) und von anderen Autoren: [e](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20722/1487), [f](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/33949/1487), [g](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24975/1487)) Aber kein einziges Mal kam irgend jemand deswegen auf die absurde Idee, deswegen die Frage nach Meta verschieben zu wollen. Dieses Argument ist völlig absurd.

Comment: **Darüber hinaus bitte ich dich, zu beantworten, was deiner Meinung nach dagegen spricht, auf German.stackexchange danach zu fragen, was der Begriff *»Österreichisch«* bedeutet.**

Comment: Du schriebst oben, dass ein Zweck der Frage ist, dass du darauf verlinken kannst, wenn Leute hier den Begriff Österreichisch in unklarer Weise verwenden. Das ist eine Meta-Frage. Bitte editiere die Frage, so dass daraus klarer hervorgeht, dass es sich nicht um eine Meta-Frage handelt. Gegenwärtig beinhaltet der Post nicht einmal eine Frage. Solange ich nicht davon überzeugt bin, dass es keine Meta-Frage ist, werde ich keine Handlung unternehmen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Du hast einen Kommentar fett markiert, und darin eine Frage reformuliert, die du schon in einem anderen Kommentar gestellt hast. Ich lese daraus die Sorge, dass ich den ersten Kommentar überlesen hätte. Falls du tatsächlich diese Sorge hast - Keine Sorge, ich lese deine Kommentare. Die Antwort ist: Falls es sich um eine Meta-Frage handelt, gehört sie nach Meta. Dass Meta-Fragen nicht so oft gelesen werden, ist wahr und vielleicht ein bisschen traurig, ändert aber nichts daran, dass wir an der Unterscheidung zwischen Fragen zur deutschen Sprache und Fragen zum Forum festhalten.

Comment: Ebenso (wie fett markieren)  tragen Ausdrücke wie "mit sehr großem Nachdruck" nicht dazu bei, die Chancen deines Ansinnens zu erhöhen. Für mich persönlich generieren solche Signale vor Allem Stress. Ich kann da nur für mich sprechen, aber es macht die Kommunikation nicht leichter, sondern schwerer.

Comment: Ich verstehe folgendes: Eine Meta-Frage ist eine Frage, die sich um das Forum German.stackexchange dreht. Solche Fragen sollte man auf German.meta.stackexchange stellen. Eine "normale" Frage ist eine Frage, die sich um die deutsche Sprache dreht. Solche Frage sollte man auf German.stackexchange stellen. Die Frage "Was bedeutet *»Österreichisch«* (im sprachlichen Kontext)" ist sehr eindeutig eine Frage, die sich auf einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache bezieht. Es ist keine Frage über das Migrieren von Fragen, über das Layout der Seite, über das Schließen von Fragen usw. Also keine Meta-Frage.

Comment: Ich bin ehrlich gesagt ein wenig fassungs- und sprachlos darüber, dass ein Moderator von German.stackexchange offenbar ernsthaft glaubt, eine Frage über *Österreichisch* gehöre in das Meta-Forum. Mit genau demselben Argument könnte man auch eine Frage über [Schweizerdeutsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27037/1487), [Bayrisch](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/56352/1487) oder [Niederdeutsch](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11607/1487) nach Meta verschieben. Ich habe es zwar schon gesagt, sage es aber noch einmal: Das ist absurd!